# form _dropdown validation for codeigniter using callback

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-form-helper

**I need to know how the validation for drop down works in codeigniter 
what need to be written in view, controller ,model .**

Below is my code but its not working .

**view.php**

```
 $options = array(
              '0'    => 'Select',
              '1'  => 'Dr.',
              '2'  => 'Mr.',
              '3' => 'Mrs.',
              '4' => 'Ms.',
              '5' => 'Prof.',
              '6' => 'Mr. & Mrs.',
            );

<?php echo form_dropdown('Title', $options, set_value('title')); ?>
```

**controller.php**

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title','Titles','required|callback_select_validate');

function select_validate() { 
 $gender = $this->input->post('gender'); 
 if($gender == 0) {
    return true;
  } 
 else { 
  $this->form_validation->set_message('check_sex', 'invalid choice');
 return FALSE; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Now it worked**

**view.php**

```
 $options = array(
              '0'    => 'Titles',
              'Dr.'  => 'Dr.',
              'Mr.'  => 'Mr.',
              'Mrs.' => 'Mrs.',
              'Ms.' => 'Ms.',
              'Prof.' => 'Prof.',
              'Mr. & Mrs.' => 'Mr. & Mrs.',
            );
<?php echo form_dropdown('Title', $options, set_value('Title')); ?>
```

**controller.php**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('Title','Titles','required|callback_select_validate');


$this->form_validation->set_message('select_validate', 'This %s is a default value');





 function select_validate($post_string) {
                    return $post_string == '0' ? FALSE : TRUE;
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ID does not match

$this->form_validation->set_rules('Title','Titles','required|callback_select_validate');

Try that one.

Comment: **When I put above  code then also its not workingfunction this my call_back **function select_validate()
{ 
   
   $gender = $this->input->post('gender');
   if($gender == 0)
   {
     return true;
   }
   else
   {
     $this->form_validation->set_message('check_sex', 'invalid choice');
     return FALSE;
   }